# Cannot find dll visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, dependencies

I'm building a class library as an addin to an external executable. When debugging in visual studio 2017, the error shows up as: **cannot load file or assembly or one of its dependencies: TD_Mgd_4.00_10, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=460a0bef3ba73253.** I tried putting the dll in the same directory with the executables but it didn't work. I checked the fusionlog and it seems that the file path the debugger is looking for is correct and I do have the dll in that path:
[fusionlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REPGd.png)
[path to the dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FxHZ.png)

Comment: You can try adding dependency manually by following this link and see if that works: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2019

Comment: If this for framework ? Are there binding redirects in your class library?